# How configure pundit to display items belonging to a parent bond

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit, rolify

My use case is, if the user have role `:agency`, he can see clients. But I have to use the link between the client's and agency to verify this. Take a look bellow to see my code:

```
class Agency < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :agency_clients
  has_many :clients, through: :agency_clients

  resourcify
end

class AgencyClient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency
  belongs_to :client
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :agency_clients
  has_many :agencies, through: :agency_clients

  resourcify
end


class ClientPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def show?
    user.has_role?(:admin) || user.has_role?(:client, record)
  end

  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user.has_role? :admin
        scope.all
      elsif user.has_role? :client, :any
        scope.with_role(:client, user)
      else
        scope.none
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way solved my problem. I hope it helps others.

My model `Agency` has many `Clients`:

```
class Agency < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :clients

  resourcify
end
```

My `User` have relationships:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :users_roles
  has_many :agencies, through: :roles, source: :resource, source_type: 'Agency'

  rolify

  ...
end
```

Need create the `UsersRole` model:

```
class UsersRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Finally, my `ClientPolicy`:

```
class ClientPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def show?
    user.has_role?(:admin) || user.has_role?(:client, record)
  end

  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user.has_role? :admin
        scope.all
      elsif user.has_role? :client, :any
        scope.with_role(:client, user)
      elsif user.has_role? :agency, :any
        scope.where(agency_id: user.agencies.pluck(:id))
      else
        scope.none
      end
    end
  end
end
```